# Sanity Check: `util.inherits(Child, Parent);`: things attached to the prototypal properties of the Child should not affect the Parent's properties?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this:

```
const util = require('util');

function Parent() {}
Parent.prototype.container = {}

function Child() {
  Parent.call(this);
}
util.inherits(Child, Parent);

Child.prototype.container['field'] = function(){}
```

Parent's `prototype.container` shouldn't have a `.field` property, right?

Interestingly, if you add another child, like so:

```
function AnotherChild() {
  Parent.call(this);
}
util.inherits(AnotherChild, Parent);
```

... it will also have the `.field` property, from the first `Child`.

wat.

Comment: Of course they would. They're all the same `.container` object. Don't use the prototype for things you don't want to share.

Comment: Thanks https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/

Comment: Sorry, have I offended you by closing the question?

Comment: No, but `of course` when clearly I had a question about the bahavior of prototypes, provided code, and wrote in clear, concise English certainly didn't come across as "welcoming".

Comment: FYI, I ended up using Crockford's functional constructor pattern.